# How to render the HTML icons inside a each cell in a column in ag-grid and make it clickable?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I need three icons/buttons in one cell in each row and make it clickable. In other words i will need three icons in each cell in specific column (rest of the column will have data),  **See attached image for example.**
*Language using: Angular and ag-grid techniques*
[See this mockup image for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHVVG.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the above functionality by creating a custom render component. checkout the similar example from AG Grid
[Rendering using Angular Components](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering-components/#example-rendering-using-angular-components)

Comment: I forgot to mention that i will also need row clickable but except specific column (button column). I mean how do i exclude any columns from rowClicked event in ag-grid table?